# how to replace HTML codes in HTML file using python?

Tags: python, html, string, replace

I'm trying to replace all HTML codes in my HTML file in a for Loop (not sure if this is the easiest approach) without changing the formatting of the original file. When I run the code below I don't get the codes replaced. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
import re
tex=open('ALICE.per-txt.txt', 'r')

tex=tex.read()




for i in tex:
  if i =='&#245;':
      i=='õ'
  elif i == '&#231;':
      i=='ç'



with open('Alice1.replaced.txt', "w") as f:
    f.write(tex)
    f.close()
```

Comment: With `for i in tex` you iterate over single characters, but `'&#245;'` has 6 characters. This will never be equal. And you never change `tex`. You change only `i` and overwrite the value of `i` in each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape).

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&#245;')
'õ'
```

With your code:

```
import html

with open('ALICE.per-txt.txt', 'r') as f:
    html_text = f.read()

html_text = html.unescape(html_text)

with open('ALICE.per-txt.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_text)
```

Please note that I opened the files with a `with` statement. This takes care of closing the file after the `with` block - something you forgot to do when reading the file.